# How get a path of resource by resource key in C# code?

Tags: winforms, resources, resx

In the WinForms project i have a resource file *Resources.resx* where i have a resource image *Image1*.
It is saved as

```
    <data name="Image1" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\Resources\Image1.tif;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
```

Now i'll get the runtime path to my resource `Property.Resources.Image1`. I know how i get a bitmap. But i need the runtime path to this resource by key (*Image1*) or just the value in xml file.

Comment: Did you add a `.resx` to the Project (`Project->Add->New Item`)? In that case - assume you named it `MyResources` - you can load the Image as `MyResources.Image1` or `MyResources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image1") as Image;`. If that's what you're asking. I'm not sure what *runtime path* means.

Comment: I can use the resource in code. I want to solve a little specific task: What is path to my resource `MyResources.Image1` during application execution (runtime).

Comment: As one of the solutions I can read Resources.resx as XML doc and find value-node by data-node. But may be there is a better solution.